# Как изменить значение переменной если мышь отклонилась на некоторое значение WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Я отслеживаю положение мыши в окне. Необходимо менять значение переменной если мышь отклонилась от текущего положения на 5px. Вот мой код:

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point currentMousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
        if (currentMousePosition.X == currentMousePosition.X + 5 && currentMousePosition.Y == currentMousePosition.Y + 5
            || currentMousePosition.X == currentMousePosition.X - 5 && currentMousePosition.Y == currentMousePosition.Y - 5)
        {
            mousePosition.Content = currentMousePosition;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Перемудрили, сильно. Вам достаточно знать дистанцию между двумя точками, где первая точка - это старое значение, которое вы сохраняете где-то за пределами события, ну а вторая - это `currentMousePosition` (я бы кстати поменял на `sender as IInputElement`). Дистанция высчитывается одним методом - `Point.Subtract(point1, point2)` (или просто `point1-point2`), в вашем случае нужен `Length` полученного вектора. Ну и в итоге получаете что-то [такое](https://pastebin.com/0cLfdXfK)

Comment: всё равно постоянно показывает текущее местоположение курсора

Comment: Странный код, вчитайтесь, вот например это равенство `currentMousePosition.X == currentMousePosition.X + 5` вернет всегда `false`. Да и остальные тоже, ведь никогда например `100 == 100 + 5` не будет `true`. Будьте внимательней. А вопроса я не понял.

Comment: Я предложенный код протестировал лично, он каждые 5 пикселей сохраняет в переменную `_lastPoint` координаты мыши, если поставить для наглядности 100, то будет менять значение при достижении разницы от старой точки до текущей >= 100. Это вроде то, что вы и просили. Так что, смотрите что не так делаете у себя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно знать дистанцию между двумя точками, где первая точка - это старое значение, которое вы сохраняете где-то за пределами события, ну а вторая - это currentMousePosition.

```
    Point _lastPoint = new Point();
    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
        var distance = Point.Subtract(_lastPoint, position);
        if (distance.Length >= 5)
        {
            _lastPoint = position;
            mousePosition.Content = position;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Этот код не скомпилируется, у `Point` нет свойства `Length`. Поправьте ответ.